# PHP - get last week number in year

Tags: php

Tell me please how to get the last number of weeks in a year?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Andy E: Not necessarily... the last week number could be 53.  The ISO-8601 definition of week 01 is the week with the first Thursday in it.

Comment: I had an example in my previous comment, but I think it was wrong, so I removed it.  Long story short: Since 52 weeks are 364 days, and a year is 365-366 days, every few years you end up with an extra week.

Comment: do you mean the number of weeks left in the year?

Comment: @R. Bemrose I know that, I was just being sarcastic because of the lack of information in the question.

Comment: I upvoted the question just to know I have a good answer the next time I visit this page

Answer (score 51):

In [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) specification, it says that **December 28th is always in the last week of its year**.
Based on that, we can simply create that date, and see in what week it is:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('December 28th');
echo $dt->format('W'); # 52

$dt = new DateTime('December 28th, 2009');
echo $dt->format('W'); # 53
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/96632)</kbd>

<sup>... or if you are using `date()` and `strtotime()` functions: **`echo date('W', strtotime('December 28th')); # 52`**</sup>

Answer (score 49):

```
function getIsoWeeksInYear($year) {
    $date = new DateTime;
    $date->setISODate($year, 53);
    return ($date->format("W") === "53" ? 53 : 52);
}
```

The `o` date format gives the *ISO-8601 year number*.  We can use this, and the fact that "invalid" dates are automatically rolled around to make valid ones (`2011-02-31` gives `2011-03-03`), to determine if a given year has 53 weeks.  If does not, then it must have 52.

See also, [**date format characters**](http://php.net/date) and [**`DateTime::setISODate()`**](http://php.net/datetime.setisodate) manual pages.

Answer (score 14):

Replace 2010 by the year you want and Europe/Berlin with your timezone:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
    echo gmdate("W", strtotime("31 December 2010"));
?>
```

You'll get one of the values `01`, `52` or `53`.

---

Just for fun ([Demo](http://codepad.org/jf2OxIm8)):

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
    echo "ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday, of 31 December:\n\n";
    for ($year = 1900; $year < 2100; $year++) {
        $date = strtotime("31 December $year");
        echo "$year => ", gmdate("W", $date), "\n";
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday, of 31 December:

1900 => 01
1901 => 01
1902 => 01
1903 => 53
1904 => 52
1905 => 52
1906 => 52
1907 => 01
1908 => 53
1909 => 52
1910 => 52
1911 => 52
1912 => 01
1913 => 01
1914 => 53
1915 => 52
1916 => 52
1917 => 52
1918 => 01
1919 => 01
1920 => 53
1921 => 52
1922 => 52
1923 => 52
1924 => 01
1925 => 53
1926 => 52
1927 => 52
1928 => 52
1929 => 01
1930 => 01
1931 => 53
1932 => 52
1933 => 52
1934 => 52
1935 => 01
1936 => 53
1937 => 52
1938 => 52
1939 => 52
1940 => 01
1941 => 01
1942 => 53
1943 => 52
1944 => 52
1945 => 52
1946 => 01
1947 => 01
1948 => 53
1949 => 52
1950 => 52
1951 => 52
1952 => 01
1953 => 53
1954 => 52
1955 => 52
1956 => 52
1957 => 01
1958 => 01
1959 => 53
1960 => 52
1961 => 52
1962 => 52
1963 => 01
1964 => 53
1965 => 52
1966 => 52
1967 => 52
1968 => 01
1969 => 01
1970 => 53
1971 => 52
1972 => 52
1973 => 52
1974 => 01
1975 => 01
1976 => 53
1977 => 52
1978 => 52
1979 => 52
1980 => 01
1981 => 53
1982 => 52
1983 => 52
1984 => 52
1985 => 01
1986 => 01
1987 => 53
1988 => 52
1989 => 52
1990 => 52
1991 => 01
1992 => 53
1993 => 52
1994 => 52
1995 => 52
1996 => 01
1997 => 01
1998 => 53
1999 => 52
2000 => 52
2001 => 52
2002 => 01
2003 => 01
2004 => 53
2005 => 52
2006 => 52
2007 => 52
2008 => 01
2009 => 53
2010 => 52
2011 => 52
2012 => 52
2013 => 01
2014 => 01
2015 => 53
2016 => 52
2017 => 52
2018 => 52
2019 => 01
2020 => 53
2021 => 52
2022 => 52
2023 => 52
2024 => 01
2025 => 01
2026 => 53
2027 => 52
2028 => 52
2029 => 52
2030 => 01
2031 => 01
2032 => 53
2033 => 52
2034 => 52
2035 => 52
2036 => 01
2037 => 53
2038 => 01
2039 => 01
2040 => 01
2041 => 01
2042 => 01
2043 => 01
2044 => 01
2045 => 01
2046 => 01
2047 => 01
2048 => 01
2049 => 01
2050 => 01
2051 => 01
2052 => 01
2053 => 01
2054 => 01
2055 => 01
2056 => 01
2057 => 01
2058 => 01
2059 => 01
2060 => 01
2061 => 01
2062 => 01
2063 => 01
2064 => 01
2065 => 01
2066 => 01
2067 => 01
2068 => 01
2069 => 01
2070 => 01
2071 => 01
2072 => 01
2073 => 01
2074 => 01
2075 => 01
2076 => 01
2077 => 01
2078 => 01
2079 => 01
2080 => 01
2081 => 01
2082 => 01
2083 => 01
2084 => 01
2085 => 01
2086 => 01
2087 => 01
2088 => 01
2089 => 01
2090 => 01
2091 => 01
2092 => 01
2093 => 01
2094 => 01
2095 => 01
2096 => 01
2097 => 01
2098 => 01
2099 => 01
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were asking how to get the number of weeks left in the year, this would do it:

```
<?php

$year = date('Y');

$week_count = date('W', strtotime($year . '-12-31'));

if ($week_count == '01')
{   
    $week_count = date('W', strtotime($year . '-12-24'));
}

echo ($week_count - date('W'));
echo ' weeks left in ' . date('Y') . '!';

?>
```

Edit: Added logic to compensate for the '01' returned by date('W');

Comment: That might not yield an expected result, because as stated in the question comments, the last week may be `01`. In such a case, your code would yield a negative number of weeks left in the year. You should programmatically convert the edge case `01` (by adding 1 to the next-to-last week).

Comment: @paul I just edited the code, pretty sure that would compensate for the returned '01' correctly... on second thought, it would still bunk out when the current week returns 01 as well... sooo close ;)

Comment: It's something along those lines, anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo getLastWeekOfYear(2015);

function getLastWeekOfYear($year) {
    $date = new DateTime();
    return date('W', strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date->setISODate($year, 1, "1")->format('Y-m-d') . "-1day"))));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With **strtotime()** you can count till 2037 cause the [2038 bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

To be sure to count all weeks of a year you must count from the 28th December, because is the only day surely in the last week of the year.

```
<?php
for($year=2018;$year<2038;$year++) {
    echo $year.' => ' .date("W",strtotime('28th December '.$year)) .' Weeks<br>';
}
?>
```

**Result:**

- 2018 => 52 Weeks
- 2019 => 52 Weeks
- 2020 => 53 Weeks
- 2021 => 52 Weeks
- 2022 => 52 Weeks
- 2023 => 52 Weeks
- 2024 => 52 Weeks
- 2025 => 52 Weeks
- 2026 => 53 Weeks
- 2027 => 52 Weeks
- 2028 => 52 Weeks
- 2029 => 52 Weeks
- 2030 => 52 Weeks
- 2031 => 52 Weeks
- 2032 => 53 Weeks
- 2033 => 52 Weeks
- 2034 => 52 Weeks
- 2035 => 52 Weeks
- 2036 => 52 Weeks
- 2037 => 53 Weeks

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, using December 28th instead of 31st is the way.
The example below returns the week number of the last week of the year according to ISO 8601.

```
for ($i = 2022; $i <= 2040; $i++) {
   $test = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', "{$i}-12-28 23:59:00", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Zurich'))->format('W');
   echo "$i -> $test\n";
}

/*
2022 -> 52
2023 -> 52
2024 -> 52
2025 -> 52
2026 -> 53
2027 -> 52
2028 -> 52
2029 -> 52
2030 -> 52
2031 -> 52
2032 -> 53
2033 -> 52
2034 -> 52
2035 -> 52
2036 -> 52
2037 -> 53
2038 -> 52
2039 -> 52
2040 -> 52
*/
```