# Getting week numbers for last X weeks

Tags: php, date, date-range

I have a script that builds an array of week numbers for the last 12 weeks like so:

```
$week_numbers = range(date('W'), date('W')-11, -1);
```

However, if the current week number is 1, then this will return an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => -1
    [3] => -2
    [4] => -3
    [5] => -4
    [6] => -5
    [7] => -6
    [8] => -7
    [9] => -8
    [10] => -9
    [11] => -10
)
```

But I need this array to look like this instead:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 52
    [2] => 51
    [3] => 50
    [4] => 49
    [5] => 48
    [6] => 47
    [7] => 46
    [8] => 45
    [9] => 44
    [10] => 43
    [11] => 42
)
```

Can anyone see a simple solution to this?

I have thought about doing something like this (not tested):

```
$current_week_number = date('W');

if($current_week_number<12){
    // Calculate the first range of week numbers (for current year)
    $this_year_week_numbers = range(date('W'), 1, -1);
    // Calculate the next range of week numbers (for last year)
    $last_year_week_numbers = range(52, 52-(11-$current_week_number), -1);
    // Combine the two arrays to return the week numbers for the last 12 weeks
    $week_numbers = array_merge($this_year_week_numbers,$last_year_week_numbers);
}else{
    // Calculate the week numbers the easy way
    $week_numbers = range(date('W'), date('W')-11, -1);
}
```

Comment: do a loop subtracting a week from the date and returning the formatted week number

Comment: @Dagon Do you mean something like this: `date('W', strtotime("-1 week"));`? If so, this will work but I will have to loop through 12 times... Do you think that is a better solution than the one I have suggested?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

one idea

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 11) {

echo date('W', strtotime("-$i week")); //1 week ago

$i++;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution because it uses the date function to calculate the week. Some years have 53 weeks which would mean the other solutions would miss out a week. Thank you! For reference, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319386/php-get-last-week-number-in-year

Comment: i had assumed you wanted real a date function not just a 0-52 count.

Answer (score 2):

if you arent scared of loops you can do this:

```
$week_numbers = range(date('W'), date('W')-11, -1);
foreach($week_numbers as $key => $value) { if($value < 1)  $week_numbers[$key] += 52; }
```

Comment: That's a better solution!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do a modulo `%` trick:

```
$week_numbers = range(date('W'), date('W')-11, -1);
foreach ($week_numbers as $i => $number) {
    $week_numbers[$i] = (($week_numbers[$i] + 52 - 1) % 52) + 1;
}
// -1 +1 is to change the range from 0-51 to 1-52
```

I've found that using modulo like this is often useful for date calculations, you can something similar for months, using `12`.

Comment: Good solution but what is with the modulus?

Comment: .. to avoid the negative numbers. `(5 + 52) % 52 = 5` (nothing changed, 52 is removed again), `(-5 + 52) % 52 = 47` (essentially 52-5)

Comment: the only problem is, that this will make the week 52 to week 0 `(0+52) % 52 = 0` you should do: `$week_numbers[$i] = (($week_numbers[$i] + 52 -1) % 52) +1;` so it makes `1-52` instead of `0-51`

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I was about to accept this as the correct answer but it has come to my attention that some years have 53 weeks, which would render this solution useless sadly :-(. In order to get the correct week number, the date function must be used. Thanks for your help anyway, still a much better solution than the one I suggested. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319386/php-get-last-week-number-in-year

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the easiest way is to create array after getting dates:

```
$week_numbers = array_map(function($iDay)
{
   return ($iDay+52)%52?($iDay+52)%52:52;
}, range(date('W'), date('W')-11));
```

-note, that you *can not* do just `%` since 52%52 will be `0` (and you want `52`)