# Calculate maximum week number in PHP

Tags: php

I am searching for a way to calculate the maximum week number for a given year in PHP. Since the last week number of a year is defined by whichever week has the first Thursday in the new year, I am not really sure how to do it.

```php
date('W', strtotime( $year.'-12-31 23:59:59'));
```

could also already return `1`, if the 31st of December is a Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday. So I was thinking, maybe do it like this?

```
date('N', strtotime( $year.'-12-31 23:59:59')) <= 3 ? 52 : 53;
```

i.e., checking if the last day of the year is a Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday and if so, it's 52 week year, otherwise a 53 week year. Not sure if that's the correct way.

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319386/php-get-last-week-number-in-year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319386/php-get-last-week-number-in-year)

Comment: Thx, flagged it as such.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `ISO` week number `(1-53)`, use :-

```
idate('W', $timestamp)
```

or use this :-

```
$date1 = "2015-12-12";
$date = new DateTime($date1);
$week = $date->format("W");
echo "total week: $week";
```

or try this :-

```
date("W", strtotime('2015-12-12'))
```

Comment: I don't want to get the ISO week number of a specific date. I want to get maximum ISO week number of a specific year. Neither of your solutions would work, `date("W", strtotime('2015-12-12'))` would just give `50`. But I am assuming that's a typo and you mean `date("W", strtotime('2015-12-31'))` - however, that would not work as well, because this would give `53` and `date("W", strtotime('2018-12-31'))` for example would give `01`.

Comment: can you try **idate** ???

Comment: `idate` would not create a different result. See the linked question for the correct answer.