# PHP DateInterval

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I have this function witch return an array of date. I need to jump on every seven days from now until last year.

```
$date[] = $lastDate = (new \DateTIme('NOW'))->format('Y-m-d');

for ($i = 1; $i < 54; ++$i) { // 54 -> number of weeks in a year
    $date[] = $lastDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 day', strtotime($lastDate)));
}

return array_reverse($date);
```

It works but I can do better.
I would like to change it because using **54** for the number of weeks in a year is not very good. (it can change)

So I want to use the `DateInterval` php class.
I can have the date of the last year with :

```
$lastYear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year', strtotime($lastDate)));
```

But I don't know how I can have my array with all my dates with the `DateInterval` class.

Can someone help me? I'm very bad with date manipulation :( ...

Here is an example array about what I need:

```
["2015-07-06", "2015-07-13", "2015-07-20", "2015-07-27", "2015-08-03", "2015-08-10", "2015-08-17", "2015-08-24", "2015-08-31", "2015-09-07", "2015-09-14", "2015-09-21", "2015-09-28", "2015-10-05", "2015-10-12", "2015-10-19", "2015-10-26", "2015-11-02", "2015-11-09", "2015-11-16", "2015-11-23", "2015-11-30", "2015-12-07", "2015-12-14", "2015-12-21", "2015-12-28", "2016-01-04", "2016-01-11", "2016-01-18", "2016-01-25", "2016-02-01", "2016-02-08", "2016-02-15", "2016-02-22", "2016-02-29", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-14", "2016-03-21", "2016-03-28", "2016-04-04", "2016-04-11", "2016-04-18", "2016-04-25", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-09", "2016-05-16", "2016-05-23", "2016-05-30", "2016-06-06", "2016-06-13", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-27", "2016-07-04"]
```

Comment: You want to count number of week dynamic, right?

Comment: I'm looking for the best solution to do that. But yes, it was my purpose in the beginning. But if there is a better one I'll take it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - get last week number in year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319386/php-get-last-week-number-in-year)

Comment: Why are you mixing `DateTime` with `date()` and `strtotime()` functions?

Comment: And you wish to loop how many times? For number of weeks in current or last year? It can be different number....

Comment: @Glavić I need to loop until it goes the same day of the last year. I have updated my post to show you

Comment: So if you have date `2016-08-16`, you need to get all days (-7 day loop) until `2015-08-16`? Should `2015-08-16` be included in array or not?

Comment: @Glavić ... if it's possible yes, but it's not really important

Comment: Should [this](https://eval.in/623222) work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP got it 's own native [DateInterval][1] object. Here 's a short example how to use it.

```
$oPeriodStart = new DateTime();
$oPeriodEnd = new DateTime('+12 months');

$oPeriod = new DatePeriod(
    $oPeriodStart,
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('7 days'),
    $oPeriodEnd
);

foreach ($oPeriod as $oInterval) {
    var_dump($oInterval->format('Y-m-d));
}
```

So what we 've done here? For a period of dates you need a start date, an end date and the interval. Just test it for yourself. Have fun.
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: Why would you use `strtotime()` when you are working with `DateTime` class? What is not ok with `new DateTime('+12 months')` ?

Comment: Didn 't know, that this would work. Never testet it until now. Great hint Glavic! Thank you. I 'll edit my post.

Comment: Keep in mind, that if you are using `DateTime class` and mix them with `date()` or `strtotime()` function, **you are doing something wrong**. Personaly, I would deprecate this functions :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("last Sunday");
$sundays = array();
$last_year_timestamp = strtotime("-1 year ",$timestamp);

while($timestamp >= $last_year_timestamp) {
    if (date("w", $timestamp) == 0) {
        $sundays[] = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
        $timestamp -= 86400*7;
        continue;
    }
    $timestamp -= 86400;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but I need to go from now until until a years past. so I need to have the 2015 date. Sorry for my english. I have difficulties to explain what I want ...

Comment: And is this past date known to us? For example, are we trying to find all Sundays between today and last year's 1st November 2015?

Comment: I have updated my post to show you. I need to loop until it goes the same day of the last year

Comment: All right. Take a look at my edited answer. We can use variable $last_year_timestamp to denote same date of last year. This code should should work just fine.