# How to get the total number of week in year php

Tags: php

How can I get the total number of week in year? Is there any build in function for getting that?

I followed [PHP - get last week number in year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319386/php-get-last-week-number-in-year) this question. but all the answer are given on ISODate which is not giving me correct answer. How can I get that?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? The answer you linked to seems to give you what you want. Unless you can specify why it doesn't work for you, I think this is a duplicate of that very question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - get last week number in year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319386/php-get-last-week-number-in-year)

Comment: I want to get the total number of week in a year. for example 2019=52 weeks, 2020=53 weeks, 2021=52 weeks, 2022=53 weeks. the link I provided doesn't return correct answer for 2022 2028...

Comment: The other question *does* return the total number of weeks in a year. If you think the selected answer gives the wrong number, why not bring it up there instead of making a new duplicate question?

Comment: Also, why do you think that 2022 (for example) gives the wrong answer? The code returns 52, which looks correct: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function to know what date is the maximum week number.

But we know it's in the end of December.
Here I loop a few years and look at the week number on a few dates at the end of the year and pick the maximum value.

```
for($i = 2017;$i<2030;$i++){
    echo $i . ": " .  max(date("W", strtotime($i ."-12-27")), date("W", strtotime($i ."-12-29")), date("W", strtotime($i ."-12-31"))). "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2017: 52
2018: 52
2019: 52
2020: 53
2021: 52
2022: 52
2023: 52
2024: 52
2025: 52
2026: 53
2027: 52
2028: 52
2029: 52
```

https://3v4l.org/18kM1

Answer (score 0):

Simply `date()` with `strtotime()`

```
<?php

$date_string = "2019-06-12";
echo "Weeknummer: " . date("W", strtotime($date_string));
?>
```

**Output:-**

Weeknummer: 24

Comment: Sorry my mistake. My question was not cleared. I wanted to get the total number of week in a year. 2019= 52 weeks, 2020=53 weeks.