# Calculating last week of the year in PHP to skip to next year

Tags: php, time

I am creating a schedule based on weeks. Now i've come to the problem that 2020 is an odd year and like week 53.

Now i want to go from the last week of the year to the first week.
I've tried some but couldn't get it to work (from 53th week to 1st)

```
<header>
  <?
  $week_start = new DateTime();
  $week_start->setISODate($year,$weeknr);
  $weeknr = $week_start->format('W');

  $week_start2 = new DateTime();
  $week_start2->setISODate($year,$weeknr);
  $yearnum = $week_start2->format('Y');

  $weekmin = $weeknr - 1;


  $date = strtotime("31 December $year");
  $last_week = gmdate("W", $date);

  if($last_week == 53 && $weeknr == 53){
    $weekplus = $weeknr - 51;
    $yearnum++;
  }else{
    $weekplus = $weeknr + 1;
  }

  echo'<a href="./agenda_user?wknr='.$weekmin.'"></a>';?>
  <span>Week <?

  echo $weeknr.' ';


  echo $yearnum;


  ?></span>
  <? echo '<a href="./agenda_user?wknr='.$weekplus.'"></a>';?>
</header>
```

I've found this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319413/11608455
but this doesnt fully answer my question

Answer (score 0):

use: index.php?date=2020-09-01 (YYYY-MM-DD)  instead? so you can manipulate the date easier.

For your "next" week numbers:

```
$date = new DateTime('2020-10-07');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
echo $date->format('W');
```

and for min weeknr:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-10-07');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));
echo $date->format('W');
```

Change the format using whatever you want it to display.

For the next and former links I would use the whole date.
index.php?date=2020-10-07

this makes it easier to manipulate the date, and not get confused with week 53 vs week 1. on which week 53 or week 1 you want to display thats all up to you.

Comment: I did what you said, instead of using weeks i made $YandW = $week_start->format('W/Y'); and putted it inside the link and defined $weeknr to the result of $YandW. But this still leaves the problem that week doesnt go to week 1 2021. How would you tackle this problem?

Comment: The problem in that question is the way you define your question; 
"Week doesn't go to week 1 2021?"  this is missing the part of where? 

Do you need to display a week 1 2021 somewhere? monthview? Year view? Week view?  Because if its just a matter of days you also might need the days as well, 31 dec is week 53 but 1 January 2021 is week 1. so it all depends on the view of which day is the beginning? do you pick january or december?

Which day to pick? well thats a matter of choice , aslong as 1 january is week 1.

Comment: Figured it out! When using time, the week number was automatically assigned week 53 when there was one, i just had to convert it to week after it.
        `$dto = new DateTime();
        $dto->setISODate($year, $weeknr);
        $time_calc = $dto->format('Y-m-d');

        $time_plus = strtotime('+1 week', strtotime($time_calc));
        $time_plus = date("Y-W", $time_plus);`

Comment: Well that is an answer, but I would use the complete date to figure out which week the date belong to.